# Using one kinect with two windows

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am a *very* newbie on WPF, C#, and Kinect. But I've found out how to initialize the kinect, and show two windows. My application is a toy one, have a full screen app with a button, when the user clicks, it should open a new window.

I've tried but two things won't work:

- when the new window open the kinect user view won't show any body
- when closing the window (going back to the main) the app crashes

The prototype window XAML is like this:

```
<Window ...>
   <k:KinectRegion Name="region_">
      <Grid>
         <k:KinectUserView .../>
      </Grid>
   </k:KinectRegion>
</Window>
```

On the C# side, I have a prototype class like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public KinectSensor sensor_ = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

   public MainWindow()
   {
      //...
      KinectRegion.SetKinectRegion(this, region_);
      this.sensor_.Open();
   }
}
```

The secondary page (with identical constructor as above) has a button that calls a function that basically says `sensor_.Close()` and `this.Close()`.

Can I use a single kinect with multiple windows? In case not (please tell me I can!) how can I proceed in having two "views"? Pages AFAIK reading on the web, requite `NavigationWindow`, and VS complains I cannot add the kinect region to that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you *don't need to close the sensor*. In order to make more windows work with one sensor:

- pass the `KinectSensor` initialized in the main one to the "child" window
- initialize the child's region

You just need to `this.Close()` without ever opening again the stream or closing it. The Kinect user view works flawlessly.